# Opening a popup from a dowpdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to open a drop down menu, and when I select one of the options, a small window will popup with more options available. Something shown in this picture I found: http://datasmugglers.com/wp-content/uploads/mute-someone.jpg

I tried some solutions I found but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work. I can't find any errors but I'm trying to do it exactly like the template someone gave me in my last question and its just not working.

```js
//toggles the hidden dropdown
function dropdown() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle('show');
}
//opens a popup window from clicking settings
function settings() {
 document.getElementById('settingsD').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
/* dropdown button*/
.dropbtn {
 background-color:#4caf50;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

/*drop down button on hover & focus*/
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
 background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/*the container <div> needed to postision the content */
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

/*dropdown content*/
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 overflow: auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

/*changes the style of the list*/
.dropdown-content2 {
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

/*links in the dropdown*/
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/*show the dropdown (use Js to add this class to the dropwdown-content container when its clicked)*/
.show {display:block;}

.settings {
 display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
    max-width: 26em;
    height: 199px;
    padding: 28px 22px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(197, 218, 255);
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css">
 <script src="dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <head>
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button onclick='dropdown()' class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
     <div class='dropdown-content2' onclick="settings()">Settings</div>
      <span id='settingsD' class='settings'>These are the settings</span>
     <div class='dropdown-content2'>Link 2</div> 
     <div class='dropdown-content2'>Link 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </head>
</html>
```

As you can see I can't click on the settings part of the dropdown and have the settings text show, and I'm not sure why. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: In HTML the`<head>` section is not for content, use `<body>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the `.show` below `.settings` in your css. If you have it like you do the `display:block;` in `.show` gets overwritten by the `display:none;` in `.settings` which is below.

Else you could do `.settings:not(.show)` if none of the css for `.settings` should be displayed.

Comment: Well that worked... sort of. It now shows up, but it shows up in the dropdown and not in the center of the page like I wanted it to. I feel like the HTML is wrong but I'm formatting the same way from my last question. Edit: Nvm I fixed it :D html was wrong